# Use different Assets.xcassets with different targets in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using multiple targets in my iOS app.I want to kown is there a smart way to use different Assets.xcassets with different targets?

Comment: Go to project -> targets (select a target ) ->  Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources you can add and remove xcassets for every target.

Comment: @rafaperez Thanks.It works.

Comment: Please check below link. However it is for swift. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52737456/2781720

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can.
My current approach is to have a shared Assets.xcassets, that have only images and colors that are shared across all apps. Then have a separate folder per whitelabel app, that has Assets.xcassets, info.plist, and LaunchScreen.storyboard, that have target membership for only one whitelabel app. There the images and colors have same name across different white label apps, so that you can reference it in the code once, avoiding hashtags or checks. This way you only have one copy of the images, keeping the app smaller. [image]