# How can we specify different targets for different assets.xcassets In latest version of Xcode 10?

Tags: xcode, image, assets

Previously we have that option for Xcode 8. But from later versions we cannot do it. Please suggest an option to do it.

Comment: Unclear what the goal is. Please give a specific example of what you’re trying to do and why you can’t do it.

Comment: My question is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568497/xcode-project-with-multiple-targets-and-multiple-assets-catalogs/52737456#52737456

Comment: I have multiple targets in my app. And have different app icons and splash images for every target. In assets.xcassets I have all the images. For example I have 20 images, 10 images need to be added for Target A, other 10 images should be added for Target B. I there any way to do it.

Comment: No, I don’t get it. Just use multiple asset catalogs.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Make sure each asset have unique name and restart the Xcode and then go the specific target and select asset in General tap -> App Icon -> App Icon source