# Assets.xcassests file in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcasset

I'm having a iOS project in Xcode that is live on app store too. Now due to some enhancements for other clients in same project I need to change some images and a little bit of code here and there. Code I'll take care of by checking the bundle identifier at run time. But how can I handle images in this scenario.

Is this thing possible that I create two or more `Assests.xcassests` catalog as the number of clients and while submitting the app I can choose which assets catalog Xcode will point to?

If yes can someone please guide me with steps.

Answer (score 0):

- Choose File > New > File.
- Under iOS, OS X or watchOS, select Resource.
- Select Asset Catalog, and click Next.
- Name the asset catalog, specify its location, and select the targets.
- Click Create.

refer [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/CreatinganImageCatalog.html) for more information!

You can refer [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488580/asset-catelog-issue-with-multiple-targets) also.

Comment: What if I don't want to create multiple targets. Like if I'm submitting build for client one I'll just change the bundle indentifier to "com.a" and somewhere i can reset which assets to be used. For client two I'll change the identifier and assets. Is this thing possible?